# $_FILES and form data

Tags: php

Trying to read if user had uploaded file or not.

HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="img" id="img">
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_FILES['img'])) {
    $upload = 1;
    echo "upload 1";
}
else{
    $upload = 0;
    echo "upload 0";
}
```

I want to see if user had selected file to be uploaded or not. In my code program goes every time to $upload = 1; even there is no file included.

Comment: Try this if(isset($_FILES['img']['temp_name'])){}

Comment: Don't try to guess how file uploads work. Instead, have a look at the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) and feel free to ask about specific details that may still be unclear.

Comment: I use if(!empty($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'])) {...}. I dont know if it is the best way, but it works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`file_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) and [`is_uploaded_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php) functions of PHP to check if file is uploaded.

```
if (!file_exists($_FILES['img']['tmp_name']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'])) {
  $upload = 1;
  echo "upload 1";
} else {
  $upload = 0;
  echo "upload 0";
}
```

Comment: I've never needed to check if the temp file exits. If the `$_FILES`-variable is populated and the `$_FILES['img']['error']` is `0`, you can pretty much count on the temp file to be there. Also, you should probably use `is_file()` instead of `file_exists()` to check for files, since the latter would return `true` for both files and folders.

Answer (score 0):

Don't check only `isset($_FILES['img'])`, check what's the value of `$_FILES['img']['error']`. If it's 0, there was no error, and the file should be there - but this should also be verified with `is_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'])`.
You can check [list of potential upload errors](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

[More details about file upload handling](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

Comment: Wow, thank you guys! file_exists and is_uploaded_file functions solved this. I guess in my method isset($_FILES['img']) just checked that there is 'img' with no proper value.

Comment: @Toni if an answer is useful to you, you can +1 it with the arrows on the Left. `;-)`

Answer (score 0):

As per the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php):

```
if (isset($_FILES['img']) && $_FILES['img']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $upload = true;
    echo "upload true";
} else {
    $upload = false;
    echo "upload false";
}
```

My example also uses actual [booleans](http://php.net/boolean). In fact you can also do:

```
$upload = isset($_FILES['img']) && $_FILES['img']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK;
```